# Structuring a Silverlight Application with Several Modules

Tags: silverlight, project-management, project-organization

I'm working on a Silverlight page which has several modules for querying and plotting data from a Database. Each of these modules is quite different and will each need their own control panels and data displayed in different formats, they will basically be unrelated, but we want them accessible from the same page.

My question is, how should I got about organizing and structuring this? Should I have several Silverlight projects in the same VS2008 solution and reference them in the .ASPX page using Tabs, Divs, etc.?

Should I try to make 1 big self containing Silverlight application? What would be the best way to modularize this inside the XAML?

Any help would be appreciated, I've done some searching online and can't find much on this subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can either have several Silverlight projects and split them up into tabs.

The alternate is to do a composite app using PRISM.

[PRISM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707819.aspx)

[Patterns For Building Composite Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx)

[Prism and Silverlight](http://www.sparklingclient.com/prism-silverlight/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! PRISM looks very interesting, I'm definitely looking into it.